Ошибка входа в процедуру не найдена в библиотеке DLL
При запуске пк выходит ошибка
Точка входа в процедуру "amd_comgr_demangle_symbol_name" не найдена. 

Подскажите, с чем она может быть связана и как возможно ее устранить?
ОС Windows 10 x64


Если вы что-то делали с дровами AMD - переустановить их. Или переустановить всю винду. Если есть точки восстановления - можно их попробовать.

Переустановка драйвера не решила проблему, попробую переустановить полность винду. Спасибо.

удали прогу от амд, поможет (по крайней мере мне помогло)

Мне помогло переустановить драйвера на мою видеокарту Rx 580, через официальную программу (AMD Software) - полная переустановка.
